# Sum item from array when value are equals in PHP and return an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array actually:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => Red
            [count] => 6
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [color] => Purple
            [count] => 6
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [color] => Red
            [count] => 6
        )
)
```

How can i create `a new array` with the sum by color like this:

```
|--------|-------|
| Color  | Count |
|--------|-------|
| Red    |    12 |
| Purple |     6 |
|--------|-------|
```

This is what I tried without success:

```
array_sum(array_map(
    function($item) {
        return $item['color'];
    }, $items)
);
```

What I'm missing here please ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Your `array_map` will remove the `count` and you only get a plain array with color strings, that cannot be summed. You could use a simple loop to build a color map and then adding the counts manually to that single map.

Comment: agree with @xander you have to loop and use `+=` to add to last value inside loop to get total count for the colours into a new array

Comment: What version of PHP do you use?

Comment: @Martin: i'm using PHP 7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterates over `$array`. Uses color value as array key, and using that to locate what color to increment the count for.

**Loop Option:**

```
$result = array();
foreach( $array as $k=>$v ) {
    if( !isset( $result[$v['color']] ) ) $result[$v['color']] = 0;
    $result[$v['color']] += $v['count'];
}

print_r( $result );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over the array doing what you're asking for:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'color' => "Red",
        'count' => 6
    ),
    array(
        'color' => "Purple",
        'count' => 6
    ),
    array(
        'color' => "Red",
        'count' => 6
    )
);

$result = array();
foreach($array as $item){
    $result[$item['color']] = isset($result[$item['color']]) ? $result[$item['color']]+$item['count'] : $item['count'];
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$result = array_reduce($items, function ($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item['color']] = ($carry[$item['color']] ?? 0) + $item['count'];

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f03b90358a6095c8ec8353cbbe63bd027a653123).